# Dropbox: no direct access?

Tags: file-sharing, dropbox

I've created a Dropbox folder, with a *.png* and *.html* in it. Obtained these links via "Share link":
[png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjcqstogq3wcmnn/Puscha.png), [html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsp62lsr8zoxmri/1.html)
However, they don't open directly. Only through Dropbox logo or download. What's wrong?

Also tried the old way through "Public folder" (which is now deprecated but could be created anyway). In this case *png* opens directly and *html* doesn't open at all (links below, in my comment).

Could anyone explain how do I publish an html for direct access?

Comment: [https://dl.dropbox.com/u/136524671/Puscha.png] and [https://dl.dropbox.com/u/136524671/index.html] - links for the 2nd method, with "Public folder"

Comment: Just now found the answer - simply replace "www" with "dl" in a link. Pity that I couldn't find the answewr at Dropbox's site, though it turned out to be there!

Comment: Sure, I couldn't do it right then because of the limitations.

Answer (score 9):

Just now found the answer - simply replace "www" with "dl" in a link. Pity that I couldn't find the answewr at Dropbox's site, though it turned out to be there!